# How to replace the tooltip array value on Fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, 3d, 2d

TextboxButton is an array.

```
TextboxButton = ["<input type='text' id='first_txt' value='Region 1' /> <input type='submit' id='first_edit' value='Edit'>", "<input type='text' id='second_txt' value='Region 2' /> <input type='submit' id='second_edit' value='Edit'>", "<input type='text' id='third_txt' value='Region 3' /> <input type='submit' id='third_edit' value='Edit'>"];
```

TextboxButton is used for tooltip on canvas on images.

When I click on first image then 'Region 1' value is present by default.
But when I change this default value 'Region 1' to some other text eg. 'Region 1 New' then how can I replace this 'Region 1' to 'Region 1 New' in the array 'TextboxButton' ?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? I can think of several ways how to achieve this, but I’m not quite sure which problem you are actually trying to solve. (string replace in the array, modify the element in the page…)

Comment: @Stefan : I have updated the above question with my latest code. Kindly take a look.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’ve failed to get your example running at all and I’m unsure of what your problem exactly is. You can find my try to get it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QckZp/). It would be very helpful to have the basics running to be able to solve your issue.

Comment: @Stefan : I have updated html code also now. Is it possible to look into it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand what you are trying to accomplish. The best solution would be to only store the value of the textbox and generate the forms when needed. Below are the changes required, after this you can edit a value, open another tooltip, and the value will be restored when opening the first tooltip again.

First, simplify the original setup:

```
//tooltipTxt = ["<input type='text' id='first_txt' value='Region 1' /> <input type='submit' id='first_edit' value='Edit'>",
//    "<input type='text' id='second_txt' value='Region 2' /> <input type='submit' id='second_edit' value='Edit'>",
//   "<input type='text' id='third_txt' value='Region 3' /> <input type='submit' id='third_edit' value='Edit'>"];

tooltipTxt = ["Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3"];
```

Next, create the form on the fly when creating the tooltip:

```
//tooltip.innerHTML = tooltipTxt[index];

tooltip.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='generic_txt' value='"+tooltipTxt[index]+"' /> <input type='submit' id='generic_edit' value='Edit'>"
```

Finally, use this code to listen to the click event on the button:

```
$("#generic_edit").click(function(){
   if(document.getElementById('generic_edit').value == "Edit"){
        document.getElementById('generic_txt').removeAttribute('disabled');
        document.getElementById('generic_txt').focus();
        document.getElementById('generic_edit').value = "Change";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('generic_txt').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        document.getElementById('generic_edit').value = "Edit";
        editedValue = $('#generic_txt').val();
        //document.getElementById('first_txt').value = editedValue;
        tooltipTxt[index] = editedValue;  // important line
        console.log('tooltip.innerHTML : ' + tooltip.innerHTML);
   }
   return false;
});
```

Please note: you don’t need any additional code for the other tooltips. By using the `index` variable above (marked the line with `// important line`) the values are automatically saved to the correct array position. I hope this solves your problem.

Further, note that you are mixing JavaScript and jQuery code. This works, but is considered bad practice. Also, you could simplify large parts of your code by using jQuery. I haven’t checked exactly, but your fade out code might be much easier when using [jQuery’s fadeOut method](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

It also appears you already solved [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17875607/1684530), so you might want to answer your own question. That way, people can profit from what you’ve learned.

Comment: Thank you for your instant reply. Will try above.

Comment: Would you kindly accept this answer then, so other know what worked for you. Also, I’m being a little bit selfish and want those points so I may vote on other StackOverflow-like sites :)